# Arch netctl profile configuration

Tags: networking, network-interface, networkmanager, ethernet, arch-arm

I'm new to Arch and I'm trying to set up my Raspberry Pi with Arch-ARM to connect to my uni's network. I think I've figured out what I need to do – I've currently got a `netctl` profile up in nano, with the interface set to the Ethernet device and all the relevant network information (IP, gateway, etc.) assigned to it. From what I can tell, all I need to do now is add the proper settings in the profile for what the network needs, but I'm unsure on how to do this. For example, the type of authentication it needs is PEAP. Does adding `authentication = PEAP` set this for the profile? I can't seem to find anything online telling me about this.

Here are all the required settings I need to connect – what configuration should I put in the profile?
https://i.stack.imgur.com/zSmgw.jpg

Comment: Please post text as text, not as a picture.  Try to copy & paste.  If you can't do that, just type it.

Comment: Did you install `networkmanager` and `network-manager-applet`? It seems the instructions use network-manager-applet.

Comment: I haven't installed either of those no, I don't have a USB on hand to do offline installs from a VM with, I guess I'm just going to have to buy one or something though as using anything other than netctl seems to be the advice I keep getting!